# Importing Android project (Material Design) into Android Studio from github

Tags: android, github, import, project

I am trying to import a source code on Android studio.

Link [Material Design](https://github.com/rey5137/material)

I downloaded this code and imported into Android studio.
But it is showing

```
Error:(17, 0) Could not find property 'MATERIAL_KEYSTORE_FILE' on SigningConfig_Decorated{name=release, storeFile=null, storePassword=null, keyAlias=null, keyPassword=null, storeType=null}.
```

How to solve this error?

I am using Android Studio 1.4.1

Comment: You only need to import **lib** folder in your project. I have doubt that you have imported app folder instead of lib folder.

Comment: I have imported all the files and folder in zip file and trying to run.

Comment: No you only need to import lib folder.

Comment: To run that project lib folder is all? 
I am not including this to other project.

Ok I am doing.

Comment: did above solution work for you?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its finding **Keystore** file but it may not available in your PC.

So you can remove that or change with new your own keystore.

Remove following lines from [build.gradle](https://github.com/rey5137/material/blob/master/app/build.gradle#L15):

```
signingConfigs {
        release {
            storeFile file(MATERIAL_KEYSTORE_FILE)
            storePassword MATERIAL_KEYSTORE_PASSWORD
            keyAlias MATERIAL_KEYSTORE_ALIAS
            keyPassword MATERIAL_KEYSTORE_PASSWORD
        }
    }
```